# Why is my Response of Type Vague on this google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am calling a Google Cloud Function. I have a green arrow beside the function. I have enabled it to use HTTP. I have enabled it to work without authorization.

When I call it I get an error 403 and an object that says response type opaque. I have no idea what is wrong now ...

I have spent an entire day on this. And I'm so confused.

I'm calling it from both `localhost:3000`, and from an app I built on https://djit.su/

I have tried my best to figure out the CORS and everything else, but I am so stuck.

At this point I just want it to return "hey" to my local machine...

Here is my Google Cloud FN:

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true,
});
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log('Made it to here!');
    if (req.method === 'PUT') {
        return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
    }
    return cors(req, res, () => {
        const stringVar = 'This is a string var';
        console.log('Hi from inside cloud fn');
        console.log('Sending:', { name: "Hi I'm Rick", stringVavr: stringVar });
        const options = {
            secure: false,
            signed: false,
            sameSite: None,
        };
        res.cookie('session', 'ABCE', options);
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
            res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
            res.status(204).send('');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my React code:

```js
async function getNum() {
        await fetch(
            'https://us-central1-provable-fair-algo-rick.cloudfunctions.net/randomHash',
            { mode: 'no-cors' }
        )
            .then(function (response) {
                // return response.text();
                console.log(response);
                console.log(json.response);

                Promise.resolve(response);
                console.log(Promise.resolve(response));
            })
            .then(function (text) {
                console.log('Request successful', text);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Request failed', error);
            });
```

Here is the console.log

```js
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be on your react code, as you are using  `{ mode: 'no-cors' }` however the Cloud Function is using CORS as it is in a different domain.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types) it explains that using `no-cors` can generate this `opaque` response:

> `no-cors` is intended to make requests to other origins that do not have CORS headers and result in an `opaque` response, but as stated, this isn't possible in the window global scope at the moment.

A way to correct this would be to use:  `{ mode: 'cors' }` The code will be as the following:

```
function getNum() {
        await fetch(
            'https://us-central1-provable-fair-algo-rick.cloudfunctions.net/randomHash',
            { mode: 'cors' }
        )
            .then(function (response) {
                // return response.text();
                console.log(response);
                console.log(json.response);

                Promise.resolve(response);
                console.log(Promise.resolve(response));
            })
            .then(function (text) {
                console.log('Request successful', text);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Request failed', error);
            });
```